# Halcon - Flip coordinate system in pose

Tags: coordinates, axis, flip, direction, halcon

How can I flip the +/- direction of a single axis in a pose?

[image]

i want Z to go upwards, not downwards..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the z-axis goes upwards, you should apply a composing between that pose you're getting and another pose who has 180° (positive or negative) in the X or Y axis (any of both will work). If I try to emulate you posing, you should have something like next:

[image]

If you apply the composing I just said, you will get something like next:

[image]

The second image was achieved with a 180° rotation over X-Axis. The code was just:

```
create_pose (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Rp+T', 'gba', 'point', yourPose)
create_pose (0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 'Rp+T', 'gba', 'point', transformationPose)
pose_compose (yourPose, transformationPose, transformedPose)
```

Remember, you would have 4 options for achieving the purpose of having Z-Axis upwards; +180° rotation in X-Axis, -180° rotation in X-Axis, +180° rotation in Y-Axis and -180° rotation in Y-Axis.